# When using FutureProvider, I want to display an Indicator for loading, but I cannot customize the size

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to display an `Indicator` during the `loading` while using `FutureProvider`, but the size remains at its maximum and cannot be reduced.

```dart
            return ref.watch(futureProvider).when(
                loading: () => Container(
                      height: 10,
                      width: 10,
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 10, maxWidth: 10),
                      child: const Indicator(),
                    ),
                error: (error, stack) => SizedBox(),
                data: (answer) => SizedBox(child: answer));
```

I tried wrapping it with a `Container` and using `BoxConstraints` to specify the size, but it didn't work. How can I specify the size of the `Indicator` to be displayed during loading?

Comment: Can you include more about `Indicator`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The Indicator is just a sample, so using a Container(color: Colors.blue) is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to set `Container` as the child of `Center`?

```
return ref.watch(futureProvider).when(
  loading: () => Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 10,
      width: 10,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 10, maxWidth: 10),
      child: const Indicator(),
    ),
  ),
  error: (error, stack) => SizedBox(),
  data: (answer) => SizedBox(child: answer));
```

Comment: I was able to solve it using that method. Thank you!